# What's the command to open a new integrated terminal from within the integrated terminal in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup a chain of tasks that need a terminal for each one. To do so, I need to use a command that opens a new integrated terminal tab from a previous integrated terminal. Is there any way to do so in vs-code integrated terminal?

In mac I would use

```
open -a Terminal
```

Or something like [ttab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttab) that immediately opens a tab in the current iterm terminal.

Thanks

(edited: I'm looking for a command to type in the terminal, not hotkeys)

Comment: hi did you find a solution for this.?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (Tilda) is the keyboard shortcut to open another terminal on Windows.
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (Tilda) is the keyboard shortcut to open another terminal on Mac.

Comment: I'm looking for a terminal command I can type in the terminal

Comment: @LucasdeGomez This isn't possible. The terminal has no API connection to VSCode, and therefore any command it receives isn't capable of affecting the VSCode interface.

Comment: No problem, sorry to have to bring the bad news, and two years late no less. :( It was @JohnsonCherian 's comment that alerted me to yours.