# How to run a script in a new Integrated Terminal window from an Integrated Terminal window

Tags: bash, powershell, visual-studio-code

Usually I run one set of commands in one Integrated terminal, then open another and run my other set of commands in that one.

I want to run a Bash/PowerShell script that runs these two scripts in Visual Studio Code in their own Integrated Terminals, within the same VS Code Instance.

Is this possible?

This question from almost 2 years ago asks the same thing with no answers: [What's the command to open a new integrated terminal from within the integrated terminal in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46452348/whats-the-command-to-open-a-new-integrated-terminal-from-within-the-integrated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open as many terminals side by said as you choose, just click the plus sign or use the hotkey noted in your link, then click that split terminal icon or use it's hotkey (CTL+).

You can of course add your own keybinding to help with multiple terminals, for example, adding these to your keybindings.json file for additional keyboard navigation to the terminal(s).

```
[
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+x", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.kill" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+j", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+k", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious" },
]
```

And the other options the author of this articles shows.
[Mastering VS Code's Terminal](https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2017/03/mastering-vscodes-terminal.html)

Yet, you seem to be saying, you want to run the script and have it automatically open a new terminal and auto split the screen to run the segment for that new one. The closest you'll probably get to that is using VSC tasks as described in the VSC docs and this article here:

[Visual Studio Code Tasks and Split Terminals](https://dev.to/pzelnip/visual-studio-code-tasks-and-split-terminals-2ghk)

```
{
    "label": "Run Server",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} manage.py runserver --noreload",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
```

> All tasks with the same group will open up as another split terminal
>   pane in the same terminal window. Very nice.
>
> rather than start each task individually, is there a way to have tasks
>   "call" or "spawn" other tasks...

```
{
    "label": "Run Server",
    "dependsOn": [
        "Run TCP Server",
        "Run Django Server",
        "Tail Log File"
    ]
},
{
    "label": "Run Django Server",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} manage.py runserver --noreload",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
{
    "label": "Run TCP Server",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "${config:python.pythonPath} scripts/tcp_server.py",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
{
    "label": "Tail Log File",
    "type": "shell",
    "command": "tail -f /tmp/logfile.txt",
    "presentation": {
        "group": "groupServerStuff"
    }
},
```

Comment: I'm not getting the expected result. I'm just seeing output like:  `> Executing task: '.\Powershell Launch Scripts\launchFrontend.ps1' <
.\Powershell Launch Scripts\launchFrontend.ps1
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.` with a `command` of `"'.\\Powershell Launch Scripts\\launchFrontend.ps1'"`. I'll have to dig into this.

Comment: Very late, but a notification about this post brought me back and encouraged me to give it another shot, and it works! Thank you for your example. The only thing I changed really was making my `command` equal `"npm run serve --prefix '${workspaceFolder}/locationOfMyFrontendProject'"`.

Comment: No worries, and glad to know it helped and you got your npm working as well.